# Working with fields in EAV on magento

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql

I have a custom attribute for min_price I need to update this field using data from the cost field using a formula.  (cost+1.50)/.84

Any ideas on how I can do this?

I've tried to make since of the EAV database and do it in MySQL directly but it's confusing to say the least.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580872/mysql-multiple-select-statements-with-an-update

Comment: do you need to do this in mysql or in magento itself?

Comment: Doesn't matter, as long as I can do it without having to export/import all the time.

Comment: Use observer catalog_product_save_before And update the  attribute

Comment: @Charlie Do you suggest any demo code is that would show me how to do that?  I can piecemeal it together from several sources, but I don't want to use bad info.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading your comments above, sounds like you want something that will update via the backend when you click save.

I have added 2 observers one for the normal backend category save and another for the mass update 'update attributes' on the category grid page.

app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            </namespace_module>
        </models>
    </global>

<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogUpdateMinPrice</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>

        <catalog_product_attribute_update_before>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogUpdateMinPriceMassaction</method>
                <namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_attribute_update_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer

```
    <?php class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    protected $additionalValue = 1.50;
    protected $multiplicationValue = 0.84;

    /**
     * Handle catalog_product_save_before event
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function catalogUpdateMinPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();

        $cost = $product->getCost();
        $newMinPrice = null;

        if($cost != ""){
            $newMinPrice = ($cost+$this->additionalValue)/$this->multiplicationValue;
        }

        $product->setMinPrice($newMinPrice);

    }


    /**
     * Handle catalog_product_attribute_update_before event
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function catalogUpdateMinPriceMassaction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Action_Attribute_Tab_Attributes */
        $attributesData = $observer->getEvent()->getAttributesData();

        $cost = $attributesData['cost'];

        if($cost != ""){
            $newMinPrice = ($cost+$this->additionalValue)/$this->multiplicationValue;
            $attributesData['min_price'] = $newMinPrice;
        $observer->getEvent()->setAttributesData($attributesData);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm running the community version I noticed enterprise_pricepermissions in your answer, will this work with community?  Thanks

Comment: Whoops, I have updated the answer now. Yes it will but use the updated version. (I just copied it from a enterprise observer and forgot to update that bit (it's just an identifier))

Comment: I think this code will work, if I knew a little more about magento.  I've got a gist that shows my setup.  Wondering if you could tell me where I went wrong.  https://gist.github.com/btray77/0e34cda8fa751524b610

Comment: Nearly :). Line 33 of your config.xml <Overnight_Pricer> should be </Overnight_Pricer>.
(Personally I would also keep the following lines lowercase : 11,13,21,24,30,33 in your config.xml as is done in the core)

Comment: did the changes, not creating log, and not updating pricing...

Comment: Sorry my fault, also lines 31 and 22 should be lowercase (which is why I reccomend this if it's allways lowercase we get less capitcalisation issues)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15553/discussion-between-brad-and-james-anelay).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time thing, you could consider doing it quickly via a spreadsheet (although I know others would strongly disagree). You could export the data pretty quickly via some sql

```
SELECT
catalog_product_entity.sku,
catalog_product_entity.entity_id,
eav_attribute.frontend_label,
catalog_product_entity_decimal.`value`
FROM
eav_attribute
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id = eav_attribute.attribute_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
WHERE eav_attribute.frontend_label LIKE "%cost%"
```

This assumes -

1. You only have the one store view
2. The attribute you're referencing is "cost"
3. The attribute you're referencing is a "price" attribute

So you can then export this as a csv, quickly process the calculation, and import it back it, either by an import tool like Magmi (recommended if you don't know what you're doing), or if you have a full grasp of this explanation, you could pop the results straight back in to the database (again, I know for many this is a cardinal sin).

**However**, always make a backup of your database before you try things like this. You really never can have too many backups.

James